Retrain old graph.pb
I have some old code that uses a TensorFlow model with a graph.pb file, and I’d like to update the classifier with new data. Previously, this was done using TensorFlow’s retrain.py. However, even after setting up a virtual environment with TensorFlow 1.15 and TensorFlow Hub 0.7.0, I can’t get it to work.
Is there a better or modern way to update or recreate the graph.pb file using new data while maintaining compatibility with the existing model structure, so the classifier can still function?

Try to upgrade the model, load and fine-tune it on your new dataset, then save it as a SavedModel format.
